# Powershell date range from calendar object to array

Tags: arrays, date, user-interface, powershell, calendar

I have a powershell GUI calendar in which you can select a range of dates. I need to be able to covert that info into an array of dates formatted YYYYMMDD.

I know $Date = "{0:yyyyMMdd}" -f (Get-Date) will work but I can't seem to get the items into the array.

I need an array like this:

```
20130211
20130212
20130213
```

Here's the code so far. Thanks for your help!

```
$Calendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar 
$Calendar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,80)
$Calendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$Calendar.MaxDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(1)
$Calendar.MaxSelectionCount = $CalendarSelect
$MenuBox.Controls.Add($Calendar) 
$Dates = $Calendar.SelectionRange
```

So $Dates will need to be converted into the array. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectionRange` property of `MonthCalendar` returns a [SelectionRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionrange.aspx) object with a `Start` and `End` property indicating the start and end of the range. You will need to just loop through the range to get the output you want:

```
for($d = $dates.Start; $d -le $dates.End; $d = $d.AddDays(1)){get-date $d -Format "yyyyMMdd"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$formatted = $dates | select @{name='date';expression={get-date $_.date -f yyyyMMdd}}
```